# Using non steroid nasal drops

Tags: addiction, vasomotor-rhinitis, nasal-cavity, nasal-drops

After light usage for a maximum of five days, I'd like to know for how long should we have a break from taking non steroid nasal drops like Otrivin to avoid addiction. An example of light usage I mean is using one drop of it once a day before bed time

Comment: Are you congested? If not, I can untag the "decongestant" tag.

Comment: No problem! Always happy to help (as I know we have a limited tag library).

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). Why did you tag your question *addiction*? There is actually a different reason behind the 5-day rule - if you thought it was addiction maybe you can change that tag for *medication*?

Comment: Yes, that's better. I'm an old big fan of stackoverflow.com but new to health SE so it may take sometime to get around

Comment: This seems like a personal medical question. Questions requesting personal medical advice are off-topic here.  To avoid closure, please try to edit the question so that it is generic. Personal questions should be taken to your personal physician who can examine you and access your full medical records. For more information, please see this [meta post](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/56/are-personal-medical-advice-questions-on-topic-here/258).